# Reduce size of dropdown in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to reduce the height of input fields. So, I have created a css class

```
.input-field {
  height: 20px
}
```

This works fine for text fields and also reduces the height of drop downs. However, in drop down the selection text is cut. How can I ensure that the complete text inside the drop down is visible

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zvn3wknj/

The selection text 'Approve' and 'Reject' is cut and not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust `padding` in input tag:

```
.input-field {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvn3wknj/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can add padding-top and padding-bottom. I hope it will work for you.

```
.input-field {
  height: 20px;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css

```
select.input-field{padding: 2px 12px;}
```